# SSIS Change Data Capture (CDC) error - "Cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode data types"

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis, sqldatatypes, change-data-capture

I'm trying to set up a Change Data Capture (CDC) SSIS package solution, however I'm getting an error that I cannot understand.  I'm getting the following error when I'm setting up the dataflow that contains the CDC Splitter section (to INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE the records into their appropriate tables):

> Column 'column_name' cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

The source table columns are of the VARCHAR datatype and the destination columns are also VARCHAR.  Destination connection manager is OLE DB.

I thought that non-unicode was associated with VARCHAR and unicode was associated with NVARCHAR.  Both source and destination datatypes are the same (VARCHAR), so why does this part of the solution think that my source data is non-unicode (NVARCHAR?).

I know that I can use a data conversation transformation to fix this, but I'm wondering if there is something that I'm missing or some other way to make this error go away.  The data conversion process is time consuming as I am setting up multiple tables with this CDC solution and many of the tables have a ton of different columns.  Is there any other option other than doing a data conversation transformation?

It's also worth noting that when I use an ADO.NET destination connection type, I do not get this error.  Why only with OLE DB?

Is there any risk in data loss by simply doing the data conversation and leaving it at that?

I tried changing the destination connection manager to ADO.NET.  This does work, however not all of the time.  When some tables have identity columns, I get a different kind of error / problem.

Comment: Using SQLProfiler find out the root cause.

Comment: Which SQL statements generate such errors

Comment: I am not familiar with CDC but could UTF-8 support have anything to do with this? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928